# How to use 'contains' in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="item-list">
 <h3>Monday Sep 21</h3>
 <h3>Tuesday Sep 22</h3>
 <h3>Wednesday Sep 23</h3>
```

If today's date is on the list, then that date should be red.  If today is not on the list (hey, it's still August!), then the 21st should be red.  I used this code to successfully turn Sept 21 red, but I don't know how to put it in an if/else.  [I tried some basic stuff, and searched, but I am lame with js.]

```
$(".item-list h3:contains('Monday Sept 21')").css('color','red');
```

(That "Monday Sept 21" will eventually be a variable based on today's date.)

Comment: An example of a good question with a good answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the [`is` traversal method](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$(".item-list h3").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':contains("Monday Sept 21")')) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    } else {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: @Eileen - yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@karim79's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263349/2162226), I see I can do a simple IF call directly like this:

```
var val = $('#customTextArea').is(':contains("Enter Text Here")');
```